# ParamCheck type error on NextJS route handler

Tags: typescript, auth0, next.js13

1. I have a NextJS 13.4 app that uses the App Router.
2. I have a route handler (`/api/me`) that retrieves profile info.
3. The route handler is protected by Auth0's `withApiAuthRequired()` function.
4. The endpoint works as expect when I run the app in dev mode (`yarn dev`), however:
5. Production build fails (`yarn build`) with the following error.

## Build Error

```
.next/types/app/api/me/route.ts:32:7
Type error: Type '{ __tag__: "GET"; __param_position__: "first"; __param_type__: NextApiRequest; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'ParamCheck<NextRequest | Request>'.
  Types of property '__param_type__' are incompatible.
    Type 'NextApiRequest' is not assignable to type 'NextRequest | Request'.
      Type 'NextApiRequest' is missing the following properties from type 'NextRequest': geo, ip, nextUrl, page, and 19 more.

  30 |     Diff<
  31 |       ParamCheck<Request | NextRequest>,
> 32 |       {
     |       ^
  33 |         __tag__: 'GET'
  34 |         __param_position__: 'first'
  35 |         __param_type__: FirstArg<MaybeField<TEntry, 'GET'>>
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

## Route Handler

```
// ~/src/app/api/me/route.ts

import { getSession, withApiAuthRequired } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
import { firebaseApp } from '@muze/lib/firebase';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';
import { getDownloadURL, getStorage } from 'firebase-admin/storage';
import { NextApiHandler, NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

const GET: NextApiHandler = withApiAuthRequired(
  async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    const session = await getSession();

    if (!!session && !!firebaseApp) {
      // Auth0
      const auth0User = session.user;

      // Firebase Firestore
      const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

      const firebaseUser = await db
        .collection('users')
        .where('email', '==', auth0User.email)
        .get();

      const firebaseUserData = firebaseUser.docs.map((user) => user.data());

      // Firebase Storage
      const storage = getStorage();
      const fileRef = storage
        .bucket()
        .file(`users/${auth0User.email}/kitmasked.png`);
      const fileUrl = await getDownloadURL(fileRef);

      // return res.end();
      return res.status(200).json({
        idNickname: auth0User.nickname,
        idName: auth0User.name,
        idPicture: auth0User.picture,
        idUpdatedAt: auth0User.updated_at,
        idEmail: auth0User.email,
        idEmailVerified: auth0User.email_verified,
        profileJoined: firebaseUserData[0].joined,
        profileEmail: firebaseUserData[0].email,
        profileUsername: firebaseUserData[0].username,
        profileImageUrl: fileUrl,
      });
    }
  }
);

export { GET };
```

I'm using:

1. `"next": "^13.4.6"`
2. `"@auth0/nextjs-auth0": "^3.0.1"`
3. `"@auth0/auth0-react": "^2.2.0"`

Obviously the parameters of the route handler are `NextApiRequest` and `NextApiResponse` instead of `NextRequest` and `NextResponse`, respectively, but I have no idea why the route is compiled to include this `ParamCheck` with `NextRequest | Request` as a type parameter.

So: Why is this happening? Am I building the handler incorrectly?

## What I've tried

I've tried changing the parameter types but `withApiAuthRequired()` won't accept a handler with other types.

I don't want to move the api into a `pages` folder and use both the Pages Router and App Router.

I've already seen some workarounds that involve creating a "super type" that encompasses both `NextApiRequest` and `NextRequest` but that feels like a hack. I want to understand why this is happening and use the tools as they were intended. I don't want to just get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't figured out how to change the ParamCheck, but after more research, my understanding is that it's redundant to use `withApiAuthRequired()` if you're also using the `getSession()` hook and requiring a valid session. So I just removed `withApiAuthRequired()` and am using `NextRequest` and `NextResponse` instead of `NextApiRequest` and `NextApiResponse`, respectively:

```
import { getSession } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
import { firebaseApp } from '@muze/lib/firebase';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';
import { getDownloadURL, getStorage } from 'firebase-admin/storage';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const GET = async (req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) => {
  const session = await getSession();

  if (!!session && !!firebaseApp) {
    // Auth0
    const auth0User = session.user;

    // Firebase Firestore
    const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

    const firebaseUser = await db
      .collection('users')
      .where('email', '==', auth0User.email)
      .get();

    const firebaseUserData = firebaseUser.docs.map((user) => user.data());

    // Firebase Storage
    const storage = getStorage();
    const fileRef = storage
      .bucket()
      .file(`users/${auth0User.email}/profile.png`);
    const fileUrl = await getDownloadURL(fileRef);

    // return res.end();
    return NextResponse.json({
      idNickname: auth0User.nickname,
      idName: auth0User.name,
      idPicture: auth0User.picture,
      idUpdatedAt: auth0User.updated_at,
      idEmail: auth0User.email,
      idEmailVerified: auth0User.email_verified,
      profileJoined: firebaseUserData[0].joined,
      profileEmail: firebaseUserData[0].email,
      profileUsername: firebaseUserData[0].username,
      profileImageUrl: fileUrl,
    });
  }
};

export { GET };
```